# Swiftui how to show sheet initially open and on click or drag it will show on half screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to show a bottom sheet on screen. By initial or start the sheet will show on 15% of screen in bottom and on drag or click it will show on half screen.

Its currently showing like this

[image]

But I want to hide this gap and make its draggable.

My code

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @State private var showAnimation: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State private var isSheetPresented = true
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack{
                Color.purple
                VStack{
                    ZStack {
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                            if isSheetPresented {
                                HalfScreenSheetView(isSheetPresented: $isSheetPresented)
                                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4))
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }//:ZSTACK
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.3)
                    Spacer()
                }//:VSTACK
            }//: ZSTACK
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - PREVIEW
struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}


struct HalfScreenSheetView: View {
    @Binding var isSheetPresented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your Half-Screen Content Goes Here")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Close") {
                isSheetPresented.toggle()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .padding(.top, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1)
        // Adjust as needed for initial position
    }
}
```

I have try to show by condition and on close its going down also but its not showing on full screen. I need to show always on screen like 10% and on click show this on 75% of screen

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be trying to reinvent what SwiftUI already provides.  Assuming you are targeting iOS 16 or above you can use the standard SwiftUI sheet with presentation detents.

[You seem to have an unnecessary collection of stacks in your view; I've removed them in the answer as they serve no purpose in a minimum reproducible example]

The following code uses the standard SwiftUI sheet, with detents set to 15% and medium (half-screen) and with the interactive dismiss disabled to  prevent the user closing the sheet by dragging (it can still be closed programatically if required)

```
struct HomeView: View {
   @State private var isSheetPresented = true
   
   var body: some View {
      Color.purple
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
         .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) { 
            Text("Half screen content here")
               .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.15), .medium])
               .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
         }
   }
}
```